# How to Integrate Facebook Sdk in Flutter App?

Tags: facebook, flutter, sdk

How to integrate Facebook SDK in my Flutter app, to advertise the app on Facebook and track users' engagement

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_sdk
use this package

Comment: It's still new, it doesn't have enough features.

Comment: @MohamedInshaf is this package workign for both ios and android

Comment: It is not maintained, and there is no null-safety migration